# how to send notification from admin to user by id with Laravel Pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

I have successfully implemented pusher on my laravel app but I want to make, when the user succeeds in making an order the default status_message for the order is `pending`, the case is when the admin changes the status_message to `processed`, the user who has ordered gets a notification that the order he has made is processed.

this is my code but this code sends notifications to all users.

**Controller**

```
if ($data->status_message == 'processed') {
   event(new OrderEvent('Hi, Your order is processed!'));

   //...
}
```

**My Event OrderEvent.php**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('notif-channel');
}

/**
 * Broadcast order event.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'order-event';
}
```

**in App blade**

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('notif-channel');
    channel.bind('order-event', function(data) {

        const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        const message = obj.message;
        
        blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: how about changing it from `Channel` to `PrivateChannel` ?

Comment: if i change to private,idk but the notif not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both user and admin should be on the same channel. For example if user is subscribed for channel 'order-channel-SetUserID'.
Admin should send the message to that channel and you should look for it on the front end and make the changes on the DOM.

In your controller when you submit the changes of the status of the order run the event with the channel name

```
event(new OrderEvent($user_id, 'Hi, Your order is processed!'));
```

Now your event should look similar to this:

```
class OrderEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user_id;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user_id, $message)
    {
        $this->user_id  = $user_id;
        $this->message  = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('order-channel.' . $this->user_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'order-event';
    }
}
```

Of course you can change your class Name etc... I'm just giving an idea.

it's important to send the changes on the same channel with this user or else you will make changes to other users that are visiting your website.

**EDITED**

Here is what else you need to configure.
In app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

You need to put the event in protected $listen

```
  protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        OrderEvent::class => [
            OrderEventListener::class,
        ],
    ];
```

In app/Listeners You should create OrderEventListener.php and set it up as follow:

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Listeners;
use App\Events\OrderEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Pusher;
    
    class OrderEventListener
        {
            /**
             * Create the event listener.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct()
            {
                //
            }
        
            /**
             * Handle the event.
             *
             * @param  \App\Events\OrderEvent  $event
             * @return void
             */
            public function handle(OrderEvent $event)
            {
                $pusher = new Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'), 
                          env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'), [
                    'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                    'useTLS' => true
                ]);
        
                $pusher->trigger($event->broadcastOn(),
                $event->broadcastAs(), $event->data);
            }
```

}

check your Debug Console in pusher dashboard? If you can see the event firing there all you need to do is show the message with javascript. If no event is running then something in your code is missing.

Comment: i trying this, admin and user is inside a same channel but notif not showing

Comment: @WildanMaulana I've updated my answer with more detailed information. Let me know if this works for you.